# Virtualhost subdomain not working on AWS EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xampp, virtualhost

I'm trying to configure a reverse proxy on an AWS EC2 instance using XAMPP.

My httpd-vhosts.conf works fine from localhost, but not from my EC2 server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName ec2-foo.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  ServerAlias ec2-foo.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/main"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName bar.ec2-foo.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  ProxyPass / http://example.com
  ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

There is no error when I access `bar.localhost`, but there is when I access it from `bar.ec2-foo.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`.

Is there a way to fix this? If not, is there a way to access `example.com` via `ec2-foo.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/bar`?

Comment: Does `ec2-foo.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` and `bar.ec2-foo.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` resolve?  I don't think they will.

Comment: I've hided the original server name for privacy reasons. @stdunbar

Comment: But does your host resolve?  And when you say there is an error, what kind of error?

Comment: @stdunbar There is no response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found out that Amazon doesn't have wildcard enabled for their public DNS. However, this can be accomplished on my own domain.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64352